# Wordpress: action/hook to get a form element value on user registration form?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook, wordpress-action

I need to create a action/hook to get a a form element value when a user submit the user registration form.

My registration form has the elements:

- user
- password
- nif

I need to creat an action to get the value of 'nif'. I found this which should be my starting point, but I don't know how to retrieve the value of 'nif'.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'registration_get_nif', 10, 1 );

function registration_get_nif( $user_id ) {

    // HERE. GET VALUE OF 'nif'....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your form has an [input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) with the name `nif` you can use PHP's [$_POST variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

```php
$nif = $_POST['nif'];
```

You'll want to heavily [sanitise](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) that variable, as it can be manipulated by the browser.

Comment: The input has not 'name', this is the input html:


<input class="wpuef_field wpuef_input_file input-text" type="file" value="" id="wpuef_upload_field_c2" data-id="c2" data-size="5242880">

Comment: From this extract from the [User Extra Fields sales material] (https://codecanyon.net/item/user-extra-fields/12949844#item-description__retrieve-and-save-fields-data-programmatically). You should be able use `$nif = wpuef_get_field( 'c2', $user_id )->value;` in the example above.